# Electricians came in last week to drill and install pot lights.. are they in charge of plastering and making sure all is OK for painting?

Tags: electrical, repair, drywall, painting, sanding

So Electricans came in to install some pot lights.  8 per room.
Some of the pot lights have cracks around the drywall where the hole was drilled.
Some cracks they created while drilling the holes were plastered and fixed by the electricans.
Some of the plaster was not sanded well.

Now our painter is coming in this week to paint the entire house.
Is the painter responsible for plastering and sanding non-smooth area's of the ceiling? (and walls?).
His job will take more time now that he has to fix certain area's of the ceiling.

Do I need to bring the electrician back in to fix the area's so the painter doesn't charge us for more labour of patching holes, sanding, etc?

Comment: What does your contract with the electricians say? That they're responsible for clean-up and aesthetics, or just that they'll only install your pot lights? In any case, your painter is probably the one person who can do a better job than your electrician, as far as drywall repairs go.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about contracts with contractors.